# Corrects sequences of parenthesis

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

Corrects sequences of parentesis can be defined recursively:

- The empty string "" is a correct sequence.
- If "X" and "Y" are correct sequences, then "XY" (the concatenation of
  X and Y) is a correct sequence.
- If "X" is a correct sequence, then "(X)" is a correct sequence.
- Each correct parentheses sequence can be derived using the above
  rules.

Given two strings s1 and s2. Each character in these strings is a parenthesis, but the strings themselves are not necessarily correct sequences of parentheses.
You would like to interleave the two sequences so that they will form a correct parentheses sequence. Note that sometimes two different ways of interleaving the two sequences will produce the same final sequence of characters. Even if that happens, we count each of the ways separately.

Compute and return the number of different ways to produce a correct parentheses sequence, modulo 10^9 + 7.

Example s1 = (() and s2 = ())

[corrects sequences of parentheses, s1 (red) and s2(blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tjCx.jpg)

I don't understand the recursive algorithm, what does X and Y mean? And modulo 10^9 + 7?

First, I tried defining all permutations of s1 and s2 and then calculate the number of balanced parentheses. But that way is wrong, isn't it?

```
class InterleavingParenthesis:
    def countWays(self, s1, s2):
        sequences = list(self.__exchange(list(s1 + s2)))
        corrects = 0

        for sequence in sequences:
            if self.__isCorrect(sequence):
                corrects += 1

    def __isCorrect(self, sequence):
        s = Stack()
        balanced = True
        i = 0

        while i < len(sequence) and balanced:
            if '(' == sequence[i]:
                s.stack(sequence[i])

            elif s.isEmpty():
                balanced = False

            else: s.remove()

            i += 1

        if s.isEmpty() and balanced: return True

        else: return False 

        def __exchange(self, s):
            if len(s) <= 0: yield s

            else:
                for i in range(len(s)):
                    for p in self.__exchange(s[:i] + s[i + 1:]):
                        yield [s[i]] + p

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def stack(self, data):
        self.items.append(data)

    def remove(self):
        self.items.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Why tag the question as a Java question?

Comment: What's your issue, exactly?

Comment: hello, well,the way I tried the number of correct sequences I get much more, in the example, instead of getting 19, I get 180, that is because it does not discriminate those balanced parentheses that do not follow the original sequence of the strings s1 and s2 sorry if my english is not right

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that shows how this recursive property works:

Start with:

```
X = "()()(())"
```

Through **property 2**, we break this into further X and Y:

```
X = "()" ; Y = "()(())"
```

For X, we can look at the insides with **property 3**.

```
X = ""
```

Because of **property 1**, we know this is **valid**.
For Y, we use **property 2** again:

```
X = "()"
Y = "(())"
```

Using the same recursion as before (**property 2**, then **property 1**) we know that X is valid. Note that in code, you usually have to go through the same process, I'm just saving time for humans. For Y, you use **property 3**:

```
X = "()"
```

And again.. :

```
X = ""
```

And with **property 1**, you know this is **valid**.

Because all sub-parts of "()()(())" are valid, "()()(())" is **valid**. That's an example of **recursion**: You keep breaking things down into smaller problems until they are solvable. In code, you would have the function call itself with regards to a smaller part of it, in your case, **X and Y**.

As for the question you were given, there is a bit that doesn't make sense to me. I don't get how there is any room for doubt in any string of parentheses, like in the image you linked. In "((()())())" for example, there is no way these two parentheses do **not** match up: "(**(**()()**)**())". Therefore my answer would be that there is only one permutation for every valid string of parentheses, but this obviously is wrong somehow.

Could you or anyone else expand on this?

Comment: There is only one correct parse for a given balanced string. But that's not what is being asked for: you have *two* strings, possibly *unbalanced* and you need to count the number of interleavings which are balanced. (There are Choose(n+m, m) possible interleavings of a string of length n and a string of length m. Of course, most will not be balanced.)